# How can I connect a couchbase cluster using Python SDK?

Tags: python, sdk, cluster-computing, couchbase, host

I've build a couchbase cluster and I need to connect to the default bucket by Python SDK.
When using a single node, I can do it using "cb = Couchbase.connect(host='localhost', bucket='default')". But for connecting a cluster, how to set the host parameter?

Answer (score 1):

As documented in the [Python SDK Developer Guide](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-python-1.2/index.html#using-multiple-nodes), you simply pass an array of the nodes in the cluster:

```
c = Couchbase.connect(
    bucket='default',
    host=['foo.com', 'bar.com', 'baz.com']
)
```

Comment: What will happen if I only put ‘foo.com’ in the array? As I understand it, the python client can utilize cluster as long as 'foo.com' is online.

Comment: That is correct, however if you only put 'foo.com' in the list, then the application restarts when 'foo.com' is unaccessible then it will not be able to bootstrap itself. By listing all cluster nodes in `host`, it can try another cluster node.